# Mock an entire package with pytest and pytest-mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a class that uses the package `tmdbsimple`:

movie.py

```
import tmdbsimple as tmdb

tmdb.API_KEY = '12345'

class Movie():
    def __init__(self, tmdb_id):
        movie = tmdb.Movies(tmdb_id)
        response = movie.info()

        self.tmdb_id = tmdb_id
        self.title = movie.title
        self.vote_average = movie.vote_average
        self.watched = False
*snip*
```

This is all well and good until I want to test it without relying on an actual connection to TMDb:

test_movie.py

```
import pytest

import movie
from fake_tmdbsimple import FakeTmdbsimple

@pytest.fixture
def testMovie(mocker):
    mocker.patch.dict('sys.modules', {'tmdbsimple': FakeTmdbsimple()})
    return movie.Movie('1')

def test_creation_of_Movie(testMovie):
    assert isinstance(testMovie, movie.Movie)

def test_properties_of_Movie(testMovie):
    assert testMovie.tmdb_id == 1
    assert testMovie.title == 'Example Movie'
    assert testMovie.vote_average == 10
    assert testMovie.watched == False
```

fake_tmdbsimple.py

```
class FakeTmdbsimple():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    class Movies():
        _example_movie_data = {
            1: {
                'title': 'Example Movie',
                'vote_average': 10.0
            }
        }

        def __init__(self, tmdb_id):
            self.tmdb_id = tmdb_id

        def info(self):
            self.title = self._example_movie_data[self.tmdb_id]['title']
            self.vote_average = self._example_movie_data[self.tmdb_id]['vote_average']

    class Find():
        def __init__(self, identifier):
            pass

        def info(self, external_source):
            return {
                'movie_results': [
                    {'id': 1}
                ]
            }

    class Search():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def movie(self, query):
            return {
                'results': [
                    {
                        'id': 1
                    }
                ]
            }
```

When the test runs, I get this error:

```
*snip*
self = <tmdbsimple.movies.Movies object at 0x110779cf8>

    def __init__(self):
>       from . import API_VERSION
E       ImportError: cannot import name 'API_VERSION'
```

The test is still trying to import from the real `tmdbsimple`! The `testMovie` object still receives an instance of `tmdbsimple.movies.Movies` instead of `fake_tmdbsimple.Movies` when calling `tmdb.Movies()`. I am relatively sure this is a result of my "not mocking where the object is used, but where it is coming from." However, in this case, using `pytest` and `pytest-mock`, I do not know how to make the mock happen where it needs to.

Am I going about this the right way? If so, what do I need to do to successfully mock the entire `tmdbsimple` package? If not, what is the correct way to test my `Movie()` class without actually accessing TMDb?

Answer (score 0):

I had a working implementation of this before, like so:

test_movie.py:

```
import pytest

from pycoin import movie

@pytest.fixture
def testMovie(fake_tmdbsimple):
    return movie.Movie('1')

@pytest.fixture
def fake_tmdbsimple(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('tmdbsimple.Movies', FakeTmdbsimpleMovies)
    monkeypatch.setattr('tmdbsimple.Find', FakeTmdbsimpleFind)
    monkeypatch.setattr('tmdbsimple.Search', FakeTmdbsimpleSearch)

class FakeTmdbsimpleMovies():
    _example_movie_data = {
        1: {
            'title': 'Example Movie',
            'vote_average': 10.0
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, tmdb_id):
        self.tmdb_id = tmdb_id

    def info(self):
        self.title = self._example_movie_data[self.tmdb_id]['title']
        self.vote_average = self._example_movie_data[self.tmdb_id]['vote_average']

class FakeTmdbsimpleFind():
    def __init__(self, identifier):
        pass

    def info(self, external_source):
        return {
            'movie_results': [
                {'id': 1}
            ]
        }

class FakeTmdbsimpleSearch():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def movie(self, query):
        return {
            'results': [
                {
                    'id': 1
                }
            ]
        }

def test_creation_of_Movie(testMovie):
    assert isinstance(testMovie, movie.Movie)

def test_properties_of_Movie(testMovie):
    assert testMovie.tmdb_id == 1
    assert testMovie.title == 'Example Movie'
    assert testMovie.vote_average == 10
    assert testMovie.watched == False
```

This had the advantage of not requiring `pytest-mock` (and also the advantage of working...), but it seemed inelegant to patch each of `Movies`, `Find`, and `Search` individually. It would also require the re-implementation of the fake classes if I wanted to test other modules with a fake version of `tmdbsimple`. It also annoys the completionist in me that I tried to mock out an entire package but can't figure out how.